# SELECT COUNT(*) ;

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, count

I have a database, `database1`, with two tables (`Table 1`, `Table2`) in it.

There are 3 rows in `Table1` and 2 rows in `Table2`. Now if I execute the following SQL query `SELECT COUNT(*);` on `database1`, then the output is `"1"`.

Does anyone has the idea, what this `"1"` signifies?

The definition of the two tables is as below.

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
(
ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
NAME NVARCHAR(20)
)

CREATE TABLE Table2
(
ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
NAME NVARCHAR(20)
)
```

Comment: I think nothing more than `SELECT COUNT(*)`, no table name. It's always 1

Comment: Hi Tass, the query is, when i execute the sql query "Select Count(*)", then the output is 1. What does this 1 signify. Please note, there is no table name specified in the query.

Answer (score 7):

Normally all selects are of the form `SELECT [columns, scalar computations on columns, grouped computations on columns, or scalar computations] FROM [table or joins of tables, etc]`

Because this allows plain scalar computations we can do something like `SELECT 1 + 1 FROM SomeTable` and it will return a recordset with the value 2 for every row in the table `SomeTable`.

Now, if we didn't care about any table, but just wanted to do our scalar computed we might want to do something like `SELECT 1 + 1`. This isn't allowed by the standard, but it is useful and most databases allow it (Oracle doesn't unless it's changed recently, at least it used to not).

Hence such bare SELECTs are treated as if they had a from clause which specified a table with one row and no column (impossible of course, but it does the trick). Hence `SELECT 1 + 1` becomes `SELECT 1 + 1 FROM ImaginaryTableWithOneRow` which returns a single row with a single column with the value `2`.

Mostly we don't think about this, we just get used to the fact that bare SELECTs give results and don't even think about the fact that there must be some one-row thing selected to return one row.

In doing `SELECT COUNT(*)` you did the equivalent of `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ImaginaryTableWithOneRow` which of course returns 1.

Answer (score 6):

Along similar lines the following also returns a result.

```
SELECT 'test'
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT *)
```

The explanation for that behavior (from [this Connect item](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/671475/select-test-where-exists-select)) also applies to your question.

> In ANSI SQL, a `SELECT` statement without `FROM` clause is not permitted -
>   you need to specify a table source. So the statement "`SELECT 'test'
>   WHERE EXISTS(SELECT *)`" should give syntax error. This is the correct
>   behavior.
>
> With respect to the SQL Server implementation, the `FROM`
>   clause is optional and it has always worked this way. So you can do
>   "`SELECT 1`" or "`SELECT @v`" and so on without requiring a table. In
>   other database systems, there is a dummy table called "DUAL" **with one
>   row** that is used to do such `SELECT` statements like "`SELECT 1 FROM
>   dual;`" or "`SELECT @v FROM dual;`". Now, coming to the `EXISTS` clause -
>   the project list doesn't matter in terms of the syntax or result of
>   the query and `SELECT *` is valid in a sub-query. Couple this with the
>   fact that we allow `SELECT` without `FROM`, you get the behavior that you
>   see. We could fix it but there is not much value in doing it and it
>   might break existing application code.

Answer (score 2):

It's because you have executed `select count(*)` without specifying a table.

The count function returns the number of rows in the specified dataset. If you don't specify a table to select from, a single select will only ever return a single row - therefore `count(*)` will return 1. (In some versions of SQL, such as Oracle, you *have* to specify a table or similar database object; Oracle includes a dummy table (called DUAL) which can be selected from when no specific table is required.)

Answer (score 1):

you wouldn't normally execute a select count(*) without specifying a table to query against. Your database server is probably giving you a count of "1" based on default system table it is querying.

Try using

```
select count(*) from Table1
```

Without a table name it makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

without table name it always return 1 whether it any database....

Answer (score 0):

Since this is tagged SQL server, the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175997.aspx) states.

> COUNT always returns an int data type value.

Also,

> COUNT(*) returns the number of items in a group. This includes NULL
>   values and duplicates.

Thus, since you didn't provide a table to do a `COUNT` from, the default (assumption) is that it returns a `1`.

Comment: Is there any reason why it should return one rather than zero?

Comment: @LukeGirvin yes, bare selects act as if run against a table with one row. Take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 0):

`COUNT` function returns the number of rows as result. If you don't specify any table, it returns 1 by default. ie., `COUNT(*), COUNT(1), COUNT(2), ...` will return `1` always.

Answer (score -1):

```
Select *
```

without a from clause is "Select ALL from the Universe" since you have filtered out nothing.
In your case, you are asking "How many universe?"
This is exactly how I would teach it.  I would write on the board on the first day,
Select * and ask what it means.  Answer: Give me the world.
And from there I would teach how to filter the universe down to something meaningful.

I must admit, I never thought of Select Count(*), which would make it more interesting but still brings back a true answer.  We have only one world.
Without consulting Steven Hawking, SQL will have to contend with only 1.

The results of the query is correct.