# Simple SELECT script giving error in Sql Server

Tags: sql-server

Below are two scripts

1. `select *`
2. `select count(*)`

1st one gives error but 2nd one doesn't give error.

Below is the error given by sql server

> Msg 263, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>       Must specify table to select from.

Can you please tell the reason?

**Note: No table name specified.**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8398772/select-count

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason `select count(*)` works is because it defaults to the `master` database

AS stated in the other answers you'll have to specify a table name.

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT *` is not a complete query

It should be

```
SELECT * from MyTableName
```

Answer (score 1):

`select count(*)` works because `count` is a function and return a scalar value, since `from` clause is optional it will execute successfully while `*` neither a function nor a scalar value that's why it fails to execute.

from [SELECT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)

```
    [ WITH <common_table_expression>]
SELECT select_list [ INTO new_table ]
[ FROM table_source ] [ WHERE search_condition ]
[ GROUP BY group_by_expression ]
[ HAVING search_condition ]
[ ORDER BY order_expression [ ASC | DESC ] ]
```

The order of the clauses in the SELECT statement is significant. Any one of the optional clauses can be omitted, but when the optional clauses are used, they must appear in the appropriate order

so select followed by any scalar value will execute i.e select 1,select '*'

Comment: Can you explain little more? With out any table how count(*) will work?

Answer (score 0):

In 1<sup>st</sup> query, to make it complete, you need to define `from` clause.

```
SELECT * FROM <Table_Name>
```

In the 2<sup>nd</sup> query, If you don't specify a table to select from, a single select will only ever return a single row - therefore count(*) will return 1.

The `FROM` clause is optional and it has always worked this way. So you can do `"SELECT 1"` or `"SELECT @val"` and so on without requiring a table.

In other database systems, there is a dummy table called `"DUAL"` with one row that is used to do such SELECT statements like `"SELECT 1 FROM dual;"`