# SELECT with a COUNT(*) in there, but no FROM TABLE, allowed, Why?

Tags: sql-server

I came across this convoluted SQL today, and please don't get hung up on what it does.

```
SELECT CASE 
        WHEN count(*) >= 1
            THEN 1
        ELSE 0
        END
WHERE 1 = 1
```

By "convoluted" I mean that it seems to produce the exact same result as this:

```
SELECT 1
```

But this question is not why it was written like that.
My question is why the above is allowed. How can it use `count(*)` when there is no table involved? Count of what?

The above query executes and returns 1 and my initial reaction was "this can't possibly work", but it does.

So why?

Comment: I knew I'd seen this before, check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8398772/select-count

Comment: Then it's a duplicate, please flag it as such.

Answer (score 1):

The same reason why this works:

```
Select GetDate()
```

In this case a single row is returned with the current system date and time. Adding Count(*) returns 1 because 1 row is being returned.