# select count(*)+count(*) is this sql statement produce any result or error?

Tags: sql, database

I have faced this question on interview with option like error,1,2,3

Now got the result as : 2

Comment: Why don't you give it a try yourself?

Comment: Why can't you just run it and test for yourself :)

Comment: Do you not have a database to try it yourself? I mean, if you attended an interview, it was about *databases*, I presume. Unless everything you know is *theory* and you don't know how to actually *work* with a DB of your choice, then ... huh.

Comment: There's always [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/)

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(*)+COUNT(*)
```

> result is 2

Normally all selects are of the form SELECT [columns, scalar computations on columns, grouped computations on columns, or scalar computations] FROM [table or joins of tables, etc]

Because this allows plain scalar computations we can do something like SELECT 1 + 1 FROM SomeTable and it will return a recordset with the value 2 for every row in the table SomeTable.

Now, if we didn't care about any table, but just wanted to do our scalar computed we might want to do something like SELECT 1 + 1. This isn't allowed by the standard, but it is useful and most databases allow it (Oracle doesn't unless it's changed recently, at least it used to not).

Hence such bare SELECTs are treated as if they had a from clause which specified a table with one row and no column (impossible of course, but it does the trick). Hence SELECT 1 + 1 becomes SELECT 1 + 1 FROM ImaginaryTableWithOneRow which returns a single row with a single column with the value 2.

Mostly we don't think about this, we just get used to the fact that bare SELECTs give results and don't even think about the fact that there must be some one-row thing selected to return one row.

In doing SELECT COUNT() you did the equivalent of SELECT COUNT() FROM ImaginaryTableWithOneRow which of course returns 1.

References : [Why MySQL COUNT without table name gives 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35576981/why-mysql-count-without-table-name-gives-1)

Comment: This would give 2 only for certain databases, for some it would give an error. I cannot comment ofcourse if this was the complete SQL syntax asked from OP by the interviewer

Comment: Try running your query in oracle. OP hasn't specified any database and I am not the downvoter :)