# Why does SELECT COUNT(*) return 1 when no table is selected?

Tags: mysql, sql, count

```
mysql> SELECT COUNT(*);
```

returns:

```
+----------+
| COUNT(*) |
+----------+
|        1 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Why is this the case? What exactly did MySQL find `1` of?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why MySQL COUNT without table name gives 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35576981/why-mysql-count-without-table-name-gives-1)